# if we have memorized the Quran by heart, will we be saved from hell fire?

Tags: quran, jannah

If a memorized the Quran by heart, will he be saved from hellfire , irrespective of his deeds ? On the internet somewhere it says yes, whereas somewhere it says not if a person has commuted major bad deeds. What is right?

Answer (score 2):

The criteria for salvation, for normal muslims are

- Iman
- Righteous deeds

It is based on this verse of [Surah Asr](http://quran.com/103/3). So its not that you can do any ill deed and get away with it.

Memorizing Quran can help us keeping away from bad deeds and close to good deeds, which will eventually lead to Jannah. But memorizing Quran in itself, is not a one way ticket to heavens.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam alaykoum

The Quran is something to be experienced not something to be only memorized, as the user @goto said memorizing the Quran only will not ticket to heaven, but understanding it through it's spiritual value and living it as your lifestyle or a philosophy of living, that's what brings the mercy of Allah and leads to heaven, here we must mention that the memorizing of the Quran will define the level of your dwelling in heavens as the Hadith narrated by Abu Dawood, Tirmidhi, Anassaii and Al-Imam Ahmed all of them from Abdullah ibn Amr ibn al-Aas that the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said:

> It is said to the Quran reader in the hereafter, read and elevated and recite as you used to recite in the Dunyaa, your heaven place is at the last verse you read.